# What is the terminal command for launching a web app?

Tags: unity, command-line, webapps, gmail

In Ubuntu 14.04, We know all Web apps run in ubuntu-made browser instead of firefox. I would like Gmail and some other services Webapps (in the ubuntu made browser) to launch in the startup. To do this, I need terminal command line to launch web app. I tried, `gmail`,`Gmail`, `unity-webapps-Gmail`,`webapps-Gmail`. Nothing I tried works. I request someone to help me.

Answer (score 5):

You can start `Ubuntu Web Browser` by

```
$ webbrowser-app <address>
$ webbrowser-app https://mail.google.com
```

Press `Super` (Windows key) type `Startup Application`.
[image]

1. Click `Add`.
2. Enter whatever you want to run at startup. For eg `unity-webapps-gmail` (replace `firefox`).
3. Click Add & Close
4. Next time you login it will launch `gmail` (or whatever you entered) automatically for you.

All unity apps. See [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7364639/).

For other services, you need to enter your service address. Replace (field 2) with `webbrowser-app http://mail.google.com` (or any other) for `Unity Web Browser` to launch with.

Happy to help.

Comment: Thanks far_sight, I got the terminal command to launch web apps. As about the 'unity-webapps-gmail' command, I have mentioned in my question, it is not working. I tried it again. It is not working as terminal command nor as startup command. All unity-webapps-... commands are not working for me.

Comment: Try using the browser command I have specified above. `$ webbrowser-app https://mail.google.com`.

Comment: Thanks far_sight, it is working fine as startup command.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the `.desktop` file that is used to launch the web app

Usually present at `.local/share/applications` in Home directory

Copy the exec command and run it in the terminal (check for the name property in the file to make sure that it corresponds to the app you are looking for).